# Maven can't read my Cucumber Test

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber

I'm currently receiving this log when running 'mvn test'

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Envirosite-Regression 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Envirosite-Regression ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\christian.nuval\Envirosite-Regression\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Envirosite-Regression ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Envirosite-Regression ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Envirosite-Regression ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Envirosite-Regression ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\christian.nuval\Envirosite-Regression\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.EnvirositeRegression.bdd.IssueTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@7a46a697
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.385 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.374 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-21T16:32:18+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My pom.xml looks like this :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.EnvirositeRegression.bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>Envirosite-Regression</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Envirosite-Regression</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-20080914.225453</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
     <profile>
        <id>cucumber-tests</id>
        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
     </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

My IssueTest.java looks like this :

```
package com.EnvirositeRegression.bdd;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        format = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber" },
        glue = "com.EnvirositeRegression.bdd",
        features = "SiteSearchTool.feature"
)

public class IssueTest {

}
```

I don't know why the IssueTest.Java is not properly read even though I added it as an inclusion in my build configuration of maven-surefire-plugin.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logs are showing **SUCCESS** with **no executed tests** because **there are no tests to run i.e. no tests are written in your `IssueTest`**. Try an example test-case, then run `mvn test`.

```
public class IssueTest {
    @Test
    public void exampleReturnsTrue() 
    {
        assertTrue("This will succeed.", true);
    }
}
```

**A side-note:**

If your tests are located where there supposed to be (`./src/tests/java/`); I suppose your `pom.xml` could do without the `<configuration> [...] </configuration>` clause, so:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 **configuration** tags one after another - try to remove one of them and see. Also, it's a good idea in cases like that to debug maven execution with -X flag.

Comment: What configuration tags?

Comment: `<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
               **<configuration> **
                    **<configuration> **
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                            </includes>
                       **</configuration>**
               **</configuration> **
            </plugin>`